# Server-side rendering with react-query but JSON is still shown in network tab

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, react-query

I have read that the only way to hide a JSON return by an API call is to use server rendering.
I'm using this on all my pages with Next.js but the only page where I still see a JSON with my data in the network tab are the pages where I use `useInfiniteQuery` and `useQuery`

On all these pages, except for app.js, I use getServerSide Props and use `initialData`

is it normal that I still see my content in the network tab?

**SSR:**

```
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {

  const { query } = ctx;
  const { page = 1 } = query;

  let resProviders

  if(!token){
    resProviders = await fetchAPI(getTalentCards);
  }else{
    resProviders = await fetchAuthorizationAPI(getTalentCards, token, configSimple);
  }
    const providersData = await resProviders;
  /*****/

  const queryClient = new QueryClient()
  const test = await queryClient.prefetchInfiniteQuery('providers', getProviders)
  const fetchedProviders = queryClient.getQueryData('providers')

  const providers = {
    pages: [
      { 
        result: providersData,
        pageId: 0,
      }
    ],
    pageParams: [0],
  }

  
  return {
    props: {
      providers: providers,
    }
  }
}
```

**useInfinitequery:**

```
const { data, 
    status, 
    error, 
    isSuccess, 
    hasNextPage,
    fetchNextPage, 
    isFetching,
    isFetchingNextPage, 
    isLoading,
    isError,
} = useInfiniteQuery(
    [
      'providers'
    ], getProviders, 
    { 
      initialData: providers,
      getNextPageParam: (lastPage, pages) => pages.length * limit, 
    }
  )
```

Comment: What exactly do you see in the network tab? Do you see the request/response for the initial data there?

Comment: Yes this what I see. I also see all the request/response done with useInfiniteQuery

Answer (score 1):

The most likely scenario is that you are getting a background refetch. If you don't want that, set a `staleTime`. From [the docs](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/ssr#staleness-is-measured-from-when-the-query-was-fetched-on-the-server):

> Because staleTime defaults to 0, queries will be refetched in the background on page load by default. You might want to use a higher staleTime to avoid this double fetching, especially if you don't cache your markup.

Comment: I just tried this. It doesn' seem to work: I can still see my initial data and all the fetched data. Also it is not working well with filters unfortunately.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Do you have a codesandbox reproduction?